# assertTrue() isn't throwing AssertionError

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion

I'm checking the presence of a button with assertTrue().

```
Assert.assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("addCustomerButton"))));
```

`addCustomerButton` contains the locator of the button.
`isElementPresent()` code is:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {

    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

When the `findElement()` in the try block of `isElementPresent()` method doesn't find the element, `findElement()` must throw the exception `NoSuchElementException`. I caught the exception in the catch block. If the `isElementPresent()` returns `true`, the assertion is `true` and there will be no `AssertionError` thrown. If the `isElementPresent()` return `false`, then the assertion is `false` and the `AssertionError` should be thrown, right?

But in my script above, the `AssertionError` is not being thrown. the test is getting marked as PASSED.

Update:
After repeated modifications and executions, `AssertionError` is thrown.

```
Test — failed
com.datadriven.testcases.BankManagerLoginTest loginAsBankManager 1542342446849 10126 

Test
com.datadriven.testcases.BankManagerLoginTest#loginAsBankManager

Exception
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
at com.datadriven.testcases.BankManagerLoginTest.loginAsBankManager(BankManagerLoginTest.java:17)
... Removed 29 stack frames
```

I've changed the locator from `button[ng-click='addCust()']` to `button[ng-click='addCus']`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - [Docs say so](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-).

Comment: Are you sure the element is not found?

Comment: You can count elements and get result based on number of the elements.

Comment: Can you show full test or more details?

Comment: Docs also say: "findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead."

Comment: @Guy I purposely gave the wrong locator to verify the functionality of the assertTrue in my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that if the condition is false, you should expect the test to fail by throwing an `AssertionError`.

However, the test will fail if any exception is thrown so all you need to do is

```
// throws an NoSuchElementException if it fails
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("addCustomerButton")));
```

In this case, you want a missing entry to result in an Error or Exception. This way you should get a more meaningful message as to why the test failed if it does.

If you want to use a method to make it clearer as to what is being tested, you can write

```
public static void assertNoException(Object o) { }

assertNoException(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("addCustomerButton"))));
```

Comment: `driver.findElement` receives only `By` object, this won't compile. In addition, `driver.findElement` will return the element or throw `NoSuchElementException`, it won't return `null`.

Comment: @Guy good point, in which case it doesn't need to check the result. I see what you mean. It was a copy-paste error.

Comment: Thanks for the technique. But I think the report looks clean if assertTrue is used.  Exception information thrown by findElement is not as clean as by assertTrue.

Comment: @learningQA You are essentially rewriting what the junit framework does for you for free. However, being a bit more verbose is often clearer. I have added an alternative